# Cannot Get Transparent Object to show up in reflections

Tags: rendering, glass, reflection

I am not sure if this is a limitation in Evee or a setting I am missing.

I am using Blender 2.9.0 on Mac OS X Catalina.

Making a scene (I know, my mom told me not to make a scene) and want to have a transparent container catch some lemons and spill them. However

[image: Object material screen space refraction enabled]

and it works fine, but NO REFLECTION.

But if I disable the refraction settings, I get a reflection, but I can no longer see the lemons!  Oddly, I can see the environment image but not the lemons.

[image: No screen space selections, no lemons, but background is seen]

I did play around with the screen space refractions of the Lemons, but it had no difference.

This does work as expected in Cycles, but 350 frames will take 7 hours to render.

I appreciate suggestions, thank you in advance.

Comment: Proper reflections in eevee are dependent on "Screen Space Reflections" (not refractions necessarily), and the presence of a "Reflection Cubemap" (add through the add menu and scale to cover the area where you want reflections to happen).

Answer (score 1):

This may be an answer from 2.9 manual...

> Screen Space Reflections and Ambient Occlusion are not compatible with
> Screen Space Refraction; they will be disabled on the surfaces that
> use it. **Surfaces that use Screen Space Refraction will not appear in
> Screen Space Reflections at the right place. Surfaces that use Screen
> Space Refraction will not cast Ambient Occlusion onto other surfaces.**

I guess I must use cycles...